# Prove a function has a maximum and minimum along a domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

Given the function $f:[13,132] \to R$ defined by $f(x)=sinx+x^3-$2 $e^x $ prove that the function has a maximum and minimum along the domain.

I understand that a function has a maximum and minimum when $f'(x)=0$ so is the best way to find $f'(x)=0$?

I believe that $f'(x)=$$cosx$+$3x^2$-$2e^x$ which doesnt equal 0 within the range?

any tips are welcome!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: Did you look at the endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), $f$ is continuous on the compact interval [13,132], which implies it has a maximum and minimum there.

Or note that cos$x+3x^{2}-2e^{x}$ is less than or equal to $3x^{2}+1-2e^{x}$ and this latter function is negative at $x=13$ and decreasing on the interval [13,132], so that the derivative of $f$ is negative on the interval, which means that $f$ is decreasing there. Therefore, the maximum occirs at 13 and the minimum at 132.